# Access form calculated fields

Tags: forms, ms-access

I am working with access forms, but I am having a problem when I try to calculate fields. I have three text box:

1. Quantity
2. Price
3. Total

When I type numbers in quantity and price field the `Total` field should get populated with the total of `Quantity` and `Prices`

I have tried a lot of formulas like:

```
=[Quantity]*[Price]
```

But nothing happens when I put the form in Form View.  In the `Total` field I get `#Error`.

Comment: you should add all the relevant tags: microsoft access in its different versions has different tags. Good tags attract more experts!

Comment: i couldn't add more tags because i am new to this page. It requested to me to have 1500 reputations to add tags like: access, calculate etc

Comment: no because my field name is price

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. Got it. Are these fields bound or unbound?

Comment: @jp2code It doesn't look like he's using code, he's just using an access form.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to go into the After Update Event for whichever text box (assuming price for this example) is entered in last and then use the code

```
Private Sub Price_AfterUpdate()
If Forms!YourFormName!Price.Value Is Not Null Then
Forms!YourFormName!Total.Value = Forms!YourFormName!Quantity.Value * Forms!YourFormName!Price.Value
End If
End Sub
```

If you wanted to be more safe, you could do that code AND

```
Private Sub Quantity_AfterUpdate()
If Forms!YourFormName!Quantity.Value Is Not Null Then
Forms!YourFormName!Total.Value = Forms!YourFormName!Quantity.Value * Forms!YourFormName!Price.Value
End If
End Sub
```

Incase the users go out of order.

Comment: @leomi Did this help? Do you have any questions?