# MS Access Insert Calculated Field to Table Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to get a form control that is doing the following as the Control Source to add it to a field in the associated table.

```
=[Company] & " " & IIf([Cable]="Fiber","FO Cable","CC Cable") & " " & [CableStartPoint] & "-" & [CableEndPoint]
```

The above displays something along the following in the control on the form when associated fields are entered -> Company FO Cable Start-End

I have tried using the expression in the After Update and the other On ... properties. This left me with a blank value though.

My next go to was to use VBA and I tried using something along the lines of VBA from this question ([Access form calculated fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30873555/access-form-calculated-fields?rq=1)) but my VBA skills seem to have diminished some and I'm not sure how to proceed to meet my needs... :(

My main goal is to not have to manually enter the information for this to prevent typos and entering redundant information that is already stored in the database such as company, start point, and end point.

If this could be done with SQL, I am interested in that solution as well. This is what I think I need for my SQL, although I'm not sure where it needs to go to update the record (After, Before, or just use the Code builder).

```
UPDATE tblCableDetails
SET CompletedLabel=Form!CableDetails!Label.Value
WHERE CableDetailsID=Form!CableDetailsID.Value
```

The reason I would like to store these in the database vs running the expression when needed, is that I would like to use this value in another table as a lookup for another form to track specifics regarding the cable.

Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of the fields are in the same table, Access Tables have a Calculated data type accessible in the Design View of the table which will handle this, quite easily. This would be your simplest route; just use your expression in the calculated field as pictured below. Note that Calculated fields have other potential limitations down the road, but I would not worry too much about that. The name of your calculated field would be CompletedLabel, and Access will maintain its value based on the other fields current value in the expression.

[image]

If the fields are not in the same table and the Form is bound and Access is handling Saves (meaning the form has a RecordSource property, and you have Access handling the saving of the record when a user changes a value, they navigate to a new record, they close the form, etc.), you could add a VBA BeforeUpdate event that stamps the column just before Access auto-saves the field. Just add the CompletedLabel field to the form (it can be hidden), then create a Before update event:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
   Me!CompletedLabel = [Company] & " " & IIf([Cable]="Fiber","FO Cable","CC Cable")    & " " & [CableStartPoint] & "-" & [CableEndPoint]
End Sub
```

In some cases you will not even need the CompletedLabel textbox on the form, but it must be in the record source (query or table) that the form is based on. It must also be editable which is likely already the case.

You could do it with SQL as you suggest, perhaps in an After Update event.

```
UPDATE 
tblCableDetails
SET 
CompletedLabel=[Company] & " " & IIf([Cable]="Fiber","FO Cable","CC Cable") & " " & [CableStartPoint] & "-" & [CableEndPoint]
WHERE 
CableDetailsID=Form!CableDetailsID.Value
```

Or with an external query when the form opens or closes, like:

```
UPDATE 
     tblCableDetails
SET 
     CompletedLabel=[Company] & " " & IIf([Cable]="Fiber","FO Cable","CC Cable")    & " " & [CableStartPoint] & "-" & [CableEndPoint]
WHERE 
     CompletedLabel = null Or Nz(CompletedLabel,"") = ""
```

You could also create a Query that contains the expression, and use it in the locations you need to see the calculated value.

Lots of possibilities. Good luck, Tag!!

Comment: Thank you for the post!
The calculated field was something I tried initially although dismissed when my needs changed.

The form is based on a query that uses three tables. I’m trying to use your suggestion about adding the SQL command to the After Update, although that doesn’t transfer as intended. Any help would be great in that realm.

Using your third option I would create a query to give me the value I want and then use it in a form that will use the table needed for tracking cable specifics. I could then use the CableDetailsID to link the records together.

Comment: Ran out of room there...
That of course is if I even need to link the records. Which I most likely don't. I would run reports based on the new table for cable specifics for individual cables based on the cable label...I hope... :)
Thanks again!

Comment: please disregard my typo to prevent further confusion. I am working on using your third option and I do believe that will solve my problem. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Awesome, Tag. Are you hitting any roadblocks with option 3?

Comment: I think I got it with option 3. Really I'm putting this together as a concept before I create it as a Access Web App in SharePoint. That is why I'm interested in a SQL solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not done with expression in event property that does the calc.

Macro or VBA code is required to save calculated data, I prefer VBA.

Is this form bound to the table you want to save data into? If so, the appropriate approach is simply:

Me!fieldname = Me.textboxname

The real trick, as you have discovered, is figuring out the correct event to put this code into. Select [Event procedure] in preferred event property then click the ellipsis (...) to go to the VBA procedure and type the desired code.

Comment: Thank you for your post! The form in reference is based on a query using three tables. I tried something along the lines of what you suggested earlier, although couldn't get it to work. I prefer VBA as well, just can't quite get it to work... :)

Comment: A data entry form based on 3 tables? Are 2 of the tables just to display related info? No problem with adding a new record on this form? What does "couldn't get it to work" mean - error message, wrong results, nothing happens? DanielG has given a lot of good info. To add to it, look into use of CurrentDb.Execute to run SQL action queries in VBA.

Comment: Lol sorry 2 tables! Yes the issue is that it doesn't display anything in the control and it does not input the data when the form is closed or updated with a new record.

Comment: This is not productive, really need to analysis db structure, query, and form design. If you want to provide db, I like Box.com fileshare site.

Comment: Figured you'd say that after my typo. :) I can provide the database, although I'm pretty sure I'm on the right track now from DanielG's third option. Thank you though. If you do want a copy send me a message with the box.com account and I'll send it over. It's a simple database though. One table for company info and another for cable details associated with the company in a subform.